# When did the Starfleet insignia change from the TMP version to the TNG version?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-insignias

In *The Motion Pictures*, we see the insignia used by Starfleet is based on the *TOS* version with the star-shape in the middle, but as at *TNG*, we change to a more simplified insignia which loses the star shape (see images below).  I was just wondering **when** this change occurred.

From this (TMP):

[image: TMP insignia]

To this (TNG):

[image: TNG insignia]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_insignia) page, this occurred sometime in the 2340s.

However, more specifically, according to *Star Trek Chronology*, the following is said:

> 2347: Starfleet Command orders a change in the design of the Starfleet emblem.  The new simplified design features an elliptical background field and a slightly redrawn arrowhead

The book does note that this is conjecture and it does not note specifically why they chose 2347 as the year, however **we can be certain it occurred between 2344 and 2349** because we see in *Yesterday's Enterprise*, the crew of the *Enterprise-C* is using the TMP-style insignia (the crew on board was from 2344), whilst the insignia on Jack Crusher's uniform in the hologram he created for Wesley* in 2349 (seen in *Family*) is using the TNG-style insignia.

*As an interested aside, it is noted in the book that this was an accident - when filming the hologram scene, Producer Ronald Moore is supposed to have noticed that Jack wasn't wearing an insignia and when he pointed this out the only insignia they could find was a TNG one

Comment: With how many uniform changes starfleet goes through, I'm surprised the insignia only had one major change in all that time

Comment: @cde yeah good point.  There was a minor change from TOS to TMP, basically the background, then TMP to TNG as mentioned above, and then the background changed in the 2370s with DS9 and VOY but that was about it.  But you're right the uniform changes really rapidly (can't even keep the same uniform from the first movie to the second lol)

Comment: Don't forget that in the original series, crew members wore the insignia of their ship or duty station